# Get data of Referenced objects in MongoEngine query, not just id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a set of models as below:

```
import mongoengine as mongo

class Post(mongo.DynamicDocument):
    text = mongo.StringField() 

class User(mongo.DynamicDocument):
    name = mongo.StringField(required=True)
    posts = mongo.ListField(mongo.ReferenceField(Post))
```

When I query for a User, say id = 1

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
print(user.to_json())
```

I get the payload as such:

```
{
     '_id': {'$oid': "1"},
     'name': 'someUser',
     'posts': [
         {'id': {'$oid': "23"}}
     ]
 }
```

When I query for Users, I want to be able to see the data of all posts for users, besides just the ID of the associated posts.

How can i get something like this instead?

```
{
     '_id': {'$oid': "1"},
     'name': 'someUser',
     'posts': [
         {
             'id': {'$oid': "23"},
             'name': 'somePost'
         }
     ]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify in your model that it should be dereferenced by passing dbref = True.

```
posts = mongo.ListField(mongo.ReferenceField(Post, dbref=True))
```